# Is there any way to keep scrollbar always at bottom using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container div with scrollbar and some contents in it. I am using it like a widget. When it initialized, I put its scrollbar down at bottom. So what I want is no matter what happens(e.g its parent element changes or be moved to another place), it can keep the scrollbar at bottom to see the content.

I know Javascript can do that. But Javascript must need some actions to trigger some events, I want the element to make it itself.

I think using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` costs too much resources.

So I want to use CSS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why'd you want to do that? Perhaps there's a better solution if we know why you want to implement this.

Comment: Short answer **no**. Just because you can do something with JavaScript does not mean you can also do it using CSS.

Comment: Javascript can use the document ready event as a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a very trick solution here: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion

So I let my outer element with `animation` property of css3

```
keyframes elementChanged
{
    from {opacity: 1};
    to   {opacity: 1};
}
myOuterElement
{
    animation: elementChanged
}
```

Then I bind the `animationEnd` event to my element, so no matter what happens to Dom tree structure that related with my element I can have a callback and do something I want.

Here is the javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('elementId').addEventListener('animationEnd', function()
{
    // do something I like...
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to disable scrolling altogether, you could move the content of the div in such a way that the bottom of the div's content is aligned with the bottom of the div.

This could be done through something like this:

**JS**

```
container = document.getElementById("id_of_container");
content = document.getElementById("id_of_content");

function set() {
    content.style.top = String(content.clientHeight - container.clientHeight) + "px";
}

window.onload = set;
window.onresize = set;

set();
```

**CSS**

```
#id_of_content {
    position: relative;
}

#id_of_container {
    overflow-y: hidden;
 }
```

My example above requires you to have a container which contains all of your content. Unless you're using `setInterval` to change the dimensions of the parent element of the content, you won't need to use it to execute `set()`.

---

If you want a pure CSS approach then you could do something like this:

```
#id_of_container {
    padding-top: 100%;
    height: (how ever many you want)px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#id_of_content {
    top: -100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

I'm not sure how well this would work though.

Comment: I have found the solution and answer the question myself, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

To always show the scrollbar at the bottom, you could just use `overflow-x: scroll;` as a CSS attribute. I could not see why a change to the parent element would break this behavior. If you want to know more, please post your code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: You misunderstand my question, I mean the scrollbar at bottom position is to see the last contents, means scrollbar scrolls to bottom.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't think there is a way around that without Javascript. I think Yharooer's suggestion is worth checking out in that case. You could call the set function he/she proposes every time something  changes in your container.